# iText: Custom Xml Tags in metadata using Xmp

Tags: java, itext

I want to add custom tags instead of default tags in metadata in PDF. 
Instead of

```
 -<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:ls="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
-<TagId-20>
    -<rdf:Seq>
        <rdf:li>arr0</rdf:li>
        <rdf:li>arr1</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
</TagId-20>
 </rdf:Description>
```

I want the metadata to be like this

```
-<TagId-20>
    -<customTag>
        <ls:userId>USERNAME</ ls:userId >
        <ls:WONum>12-110992</ WONum >
    </customTag >
</TagId-20>
```

I found somewhere that... to have custom xml tags, I need to extend XmpArray and implement the toString() method.

I implemented the following..

```
public class CustomXmpArray extends XmpArray {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4551741336974797330L;

public CustomXmpArray() {
    super("dummy");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
    String s;
    for (String string : this) {
        s = string;
        buf.append(s);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
}
```

One problem I am facing here is, I don’t need the "type" variable, but  XmpArray doesnot have a no-argument constructor, and so I am forced to being pass a dummy value to super class XmpArray. I am wrong in my implementation?

Why XmpArray doesnot have no-argument constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm puzzled. Why do you need `XmpArray`?

How are you adding your custom `XML` to the XmpWriter?

There are two options.

1. You create your own `XmpSchema` implementation and you use the `addRdfDescription(XmpSchema s)` method. In this case, you'll use objects such as `XmpArray` and `LangAlt` to add specific types of content to the `XmpSchema` object. It seems that you want to avoid this, so you probably want:
2. You create your own String containing your own XML and you use the addRdfDescription(String xmlns, String content) method.

Let me quote from the XMP specification:

The rdf:RDF element can contain zero or more rdf:Description elements. The following example shows a single rdf:Description element:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        ... Dublin Core properties go here
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I think you alread have the `<rdf:RDF>` tag. You also have an `<rdf:Description>` tag. Instead of a standard schema such as Dublin core, you want a custom schema.

If you want to avoid having this `<rdf:Description>` tag, then you're asking us to show you how to do something that violates the specification. We're not going to do that.

If you want to have some custom XML inside this `<rdf:Description>` tag, then it's sufficient to do something like this:

```
xmpWriter.addRdfDescription("", "<TagId-20><customTag><ls:userId>USERNAME</ ls:userId ><ls:WONum>12-110992</ WONum ></customTag ></TagId-20>");
```

The result will be:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="" >
        <TagId-20>
            <customTag>
                <ls:userId>USERNAME</ ls:userId >
                <ls:WONum>12-110992</ WONum >
            </customTag >
        </TagId-20>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Isn't that what you want? If not, you'll have to clarify.

Also: it would be better if you also define a namespace, instead of passing an empty string for the `xmlns` parameter.

By the way: you may want to read the [XMP specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xmp/sdk/XMPspecification.pdf).

Comment: Yes.! that's what I wanted.. 
I got some post related to this which said.. if i want to change the default tags <rdf:Seq> or <rdf:li> and have my own structure, I need to extend XmpArray and implement toString method. Hence I followed that approach.
The solution given by you is much straight-forward. Thank you..

Comment: OK, if the answer works for you, please click "accept" to accept the answer.